# Flutter Retrieve Data Using Node.js From MySQL Empty

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter, express

I have data in MySQL and tried to retrieve data using Flutter which using API endpoint created from Express Node.js, here is the code :

```
import express from 'express';
import mysql from 'mysql';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import jualmRouter from './routes/jualm.js';
import barangRouter from './routes/barang.js';
import belimRouter from './routes/belim.js';

const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
//const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const jualmRouter = require('./routes/jualm');
// const barangRouter = require('./routes/barang');
// const belimRouter = require('./routes/belim');
const books = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Alice in Wonderland', author: 'Lewis Carrol'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Around the World in eighty days', author: 'Jules Verne'},
  {id: 3, title: 'Utopia', author: 'Sir Thomas Moor'},
 ]

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use('/api/jualm', jualmRouter);
app.use('/api/barang', barangRouter);
app.use('/api/belim', belimRouter);

app.get('/api/books', (req, res) => {
  res.json(books)
 })

 // MySQL connection configuration
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'hotel',
});

// Route to fetch data from tbjualm table
app.get('/api/jualm', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT subject,location,fkota FROM appointments', (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error executing MySQL query:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve data from database' });
    }
    res.json(results);
  });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

from express node.js, we can see I have API endpoint which get data books (Mapping Array) and data from table appointments (this one from MySQL). Now the API endpoint if I put directly into browser, both data could show the result. Nothing wrong here.

Now this is my flutter code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Data {
  final String subject;
  final String location;
  final String fkota;

  Data({
    required this.subject,
    required this.location,
    required this.fkota,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      subject: json['subject'],
      location: json['location'],
      fkota: json['fkota'],
    );
  }
}

class Book {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book({required this.id, required this.title, required this.author});

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      author: json['author'],
    );
  }
}
class BooksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_BooksScreenState createState() => _BooksScreenState();
}
class _BooksScreenState extends State<BooksScreen> {
  List<Book> _books = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchBooks();
  }
  Future<void> _fetchBooks() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/api/books'));
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
      _books = json.map((item) => Book.fromJson(item)).toList();
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load books');
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Books'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _books.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_books[index].title),
            subtitle: Text(_books[index].author),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
 }

class TableFromApi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableFromApiState createState() => _TableFromApiState();
}

class _TableFromApiState extends State<TableFromApi> {
  List<Data> _data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/api/jualm'));
    print (response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _data = json.map((item) => Data.fromJson(item)).toList();
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Data ${_data.length}"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_data[index].subject),
            subtitle: Text(_data[index].location),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: TableFromApi(),
  ));
}
```

But in flutter, the result from `BookScreen` doesn't have trouble to retrieve data from `Books` data, but the MySQL Data can not be shown.
If I get the API endpoint and directly into browser, the result both of them just fine.

Please give me insight. thank you, need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it seems somehow data from MySQL we need to make sure none of these fields have NULL value, apparently my data have NULL value. So we need to check the null value during variable declaration.

```
class Data {
  final String subject;
  final String location;
  final String fkota;

  Data({
    required this.subject,
    required this.location,
    required this.fkota,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      subject: json['subject']!.toString(),
      location: json['location'] ?? '',
      fkota: json['fkota'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is revised class Data, with checking for null value and make sure the data converted to String.
Thank you. Now it's working